# Can memoization be used with an iterative solution in dynamic programming?

Tags: recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming

For example, the Fibonacci sequence can be solved with memoization when using recursion. But can solving Fibonacci iteratively (stack + while loop) also take advantage of memoization?

Comment: Any recursive algorithm can be converted to a functionally identical iterative one, so yes. If you understand how to convert Fibonacci from recursive to iterative as well as how to implement memoization for the recursive version, you should have no problem implementing memoization for the iterative version.

Comment: @Dukeling what is there to memoize in the iterative solution? nothing. you already work forward on a store, reusing the stored values is the meaning of it being a dynamic programming approach. talking about memoization in dynamic (iterative) setting makes no sense.

Comment: @WillNess If you're implementing the recursive solution iteratively in a functionally identical way, it would take exponential time if you don't reuse previously calculated values. But of course doing this with Fibonacci is unnecessary, as there's a simpler iterative solution. There isn't just one way to do it iteratively.

Comment: @WillNess recursive memoization can work with a top-down solution. Are you saying that an iterative solution must work bottom-up to have the same advantage? Is there a way to work iteratively, top-down and still get a memoization benefit?

Comment: @GabrielJohnRodriguez I'm saying iterative, dynamic solution is by definition bottom-up. It explicates the memoization in the dynamic store and thus obviates it. top-down OTOH is recursive. recursive is top-down. IMO. either we are counting down (and remembering previous values behind the scenes helps greatly), or we are counting up (and so we are producing the values incrementally by design, explicitly).

Comment: @Dukeling "iteratively" already means that I'm counting up,  using smaller values to produce next ones. if I'm not using previously produced values then it's not an iterative solution, no?

Comment: [Memoization](https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization) "is a technique for storing values of a function instead of recomputing them each time the function is called" with the same arguments, but in iterative/ dynamic programming solutions each argument value is processed only *once*, so there are no repeated calls, and the whole process is arranged so that there is a gradual build-up of knowledge toward getting the final answer.

Comment: @WillNess I consider any loop (for/while) to be iterative (which includes a while loop with a stack that exactly emulates recursion), if you don't agree, I guess we just have different definitions then.

Answer (score 0):

Of course ... start at the base case F(0) and F(1), and compute values.  Keep them all in an array, indexed by the functional subscript.  When you get an input argument greater than your current array extent, compute more values.  When you get one within the current bounds, simply return that value from the array.